# How to check whether element contains another element by tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML:

```
<div class="1">
    <div class="2">
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="3">
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to go through all `div` and find `div` that only have `span`. It must be `div.2` and `div.3`.

So I need to modify `if` condition:

```
var divArr = table.querySelectorAll("div");

for(var i = 0; i < divArr.length; i++){
    if(divArr[i].querySelector("span")){

    }
}
```

I suppose using `:has` (but I don't want to use jQuery) or `.contains`, but I need help.

Comment: What's wrong with your current condition? Your expectation is not very clear... (consider adding a code snippet)

Comment: @benams Now I also have `div.1` in my selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `nodeName` property with `SPAN` like the following:

```js
var divArr = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divArr.length; i++) {
  if(divArr[i].children[0].nodeName == 'SPAN'){
    console.log(divArr[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="3">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR:** You can target the parent node like the following:

```js
var divArr = document.querySelectorAll("div > span");

for(var i = 0; i < divArr.length; i++){
    console.log(divArr[i].parentNode)
}
```

```html
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="3">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
let divs = [], 
  spans = document.body.querySelectorAll('div>span:only-child'),
  i = 0, ii = spans.length;

for (i; i<ii; i++){
  divs.push(spans[i].parentNode)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But if I have more than one `span` in `div`?

Comment: I thought you are looking for something that matches perfectly your structure. If it's so then you should use the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with you code, I ended up with this snippet:

```js
spans = document.body.querySelectorAll('div > span');
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].parentNode.classList.add("highlight");
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="3">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="4">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="5">
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added some other cases in the HTML,
and added `highlight` in CSS to show what's the result of the JS.